# 3DPlot, Logarithmic x and y axes, Interpolating function

Tags: plotting, interpolation

I've used NDSolve to get an InterpolatingFunction that solves a certain difeq. I want to see the behavior of this function on a couple different scales, so I want to use some sort of Log Plot.

For a regular function in a 3D plot, I would do something like

```
Plot3D[F[10^x,10^t],{x,1,5},{t,1,5}]
```

but this gives me error messages for the interpolating function:

InterpolatingFunction::dmval: Input value {1,1} lies outside the range of data in the interpolating function. Extrapolation will be used.

A blank plot is shown.

The actual argument, i.e., 10^1, is clearly in the range of data, even if (1,1) is not. Is there a way around this issue?

Sorry I didn't post actual code, the difeq is complicated and I thought it would only muddle things. If it would help, I'll try to create a simple example.

Comment: More code would be helpful. Please format.

Comment: I don't think we need to see the `NDSolve` command, you could post the interpolating function itself.  If `F` is your interpolating function, evaluate `CopyToClipboard[F]`, then go to pastebin.com and paste the definition there and give the link here.